# Is it important to backup and restore DFSR/Private folder for Windows DFS replication group?

Tags: windows, backup, dfs

Strangely, there doesn't appear to be a whole lot of direction on this and it doesn't seem that even the backup vendors can provide a straight answer.

In a Windows DFS replication group, each server maintains a folder `DfsrPrivate` under each replicated folder to track `ConflictAndDeleted` files, `Staging` files, etc. This folder is an NTFS junction to a separate folder under `System Volume Information\DFSR\Private`.

During the course of the day, DFS produces quite a bit of file system changes under these folders for what is essentially un-needed data. This can cause larger than normal incremental backups.

My question - **Is it important to backup this folder?**

What will happen during a restore if the root "Private" folder, or a subset of folders are not restored? What about the relationship with the Junction points?

Note - These specific folders do NOT contain the DFS database and configuration files. That information will be backed up and restored.